# Regular expression to match a sentence

Tags: java, regex

I have used regular expression

```
(.*)(\s){1}([0-9]*min|lightning)\b
```

to match a string like the following:

1. Writing Fast Tests Against Enterprise Rails 60min
2. Clojure Ate Scala (on my project) 45min
3. Accounting-Driven Development 45min

The matcher group will give:

1. Writing Fast Tests Against Enterprise Rails
2. Space
3. 60 mins

But a string like `???????????????????? 60min` also matches.

Can anyone help me out with this?

**Updated**

As per the answer regex like below  will solve it but for input 3

```
 ^([^XX]*)(\s){1}([0-9]*min|lightning)\b$
```

1. i want to allow - so that input 3 matches. String like as below will
   also match which is not correct
2. Group 1 should contain only alphabets

   ------------ 60min

Please see the link https://regex101.com/r/JH5sl1/6

Comment: it seems its an assignment from thoughtworks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `(.*)(\s){1}([0-9]*min|lightning)\b` to `^([\w ]*)(\s){1}([0-9]*min|lightning)\b$`.

It will ensure that you match only alphanumerics and spaces at the start of the string. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/JH5sl1/1).

Since the question is evolving, let's take the issue on the other way. Change your regex to:

```
^([^XX]*)(\s){1}([0-9]*min|lightning)\b$
  ^^^^^
```

And change `XX` to whatever you **don't want to match.** It's called a negated character class and allow you "refuse" the characters it contains.

---

If you want to avoid the presence of two consecutive non alphanumeric chars, you can use a negative lookahead:

```
^(?!.*(\W)\1)(\D*)\s(\d*min|lightning)$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JH5sl1/7)

Comment: @ThomasAyoub this doesn't match OPs second sample string, as there are parenthesis in. You might include them into your character class, but I'd guess it'd grow larger and larger with further samples.

Comment: How about string Accounting-Driven Development 45min

Comment: [\w ] it has a space after w.can i write it as [\w\s]

Comment: @coder25 `\s` matches more than a simple space (tabs, newlines etc.)

Comment: is there other symbol to match a single space,For pattern 3 mentioned in code edit Accounting-Driven Development,If i allow "-" character then will string -------------------------- 60 min will be valid

Comment: @ThomasAyoub another idea might be something like `^\W{0,3}(\w+\W{1,3})+([0-9]*min|lightning)$`, checking for a mix of word and non-word-characters, without too many consecutive non-words present. But it's more or less blind guessing.